# Lie Algebra of $GL_{+}(n,\mathbb C)$

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-groups

My question is if the Lie algebra of $GL_{+}(n,\mathbb C)$ = {$A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n} |\det(A) > 0$} is the same as of $GL(n,\mathbb C)$. Futhermore I have a problems understanding what is the underlying manifold of these two Lie groups (are they also the same?).

Comment: What does it mean for a complex number to be greater than $0$?

Answer (score 1):

For complex numbers, $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ is already connected, so there is only one connected component.

[What's an easy way to show that $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974825/whats-an-easy-way-to-show-that-gln-mathbb-c-is-connected?noredirect=1&lq=1)